# image showing like <img alt="" index.jpg"}}"="" wysiwyg="" src="{{media url="> in magento frontend

Tags: magento-1.7

I have added one custom attribute in category section in admin.
when I have uploaded image, it's look like

in frontend.

I have use  $_category->getBannername();  code for display attribute in magento frontend on category page.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

Use the Below Code :

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($text);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to *System -> Configuration -> Catalogue -> frontend* and check option:
*Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories* set it as "Yes"

Underneath that dropdown you can see comment as below too.
E.g. `{{media url="path/to/image.jpg"}} {{skin url="path/to/picture.gif"}}`. Dynamic directives parsing impacts catalog performance.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($text);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php 

replace (line 178) 

$directive = sprintf('{{media url="%s"}}', $mediaPath);
```

**with**

```
$directive = sprintf("{{media url='%s'}}", $mediaPath);
```