# Magento return wrong media url on frontend

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Im stuck on wired situation. The thing i do is getting magento blog data and show on specific page. The problem is magento return the wrong media URL on front end like this `<img alt="" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" blogimg1.jpg"}}"="">`. All i want it will return image src like this "mydomain.com/images/blogimg1.jpg". I try to find solution but couldnot succeed.

My code is below

```
                <?php 
                    $collections = Mage::getModel('blog/blog')->getCollection()
                   ->addPresentFilter()
                   ->addEnableFilter(AW_Blog_Model_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                   ->addStoreFilter()
                   ->joinComments()
                   ->setOrder('created_time', 'desc');
                   foreach ($collections as $collection) {
                       echo $collection->title."<br>";
                       echo $collection->post_content."<br>";
                       echo $collection->short_content."<br>";
                   }
                ?>
```

Comment: why are you try to get media url as your image is not in media folder. Its in your root directory. so you need base url for that.

Comment: each blog consist some text plus 1 or 2 images . When i fetch the data , the returing text is correct but the image url is return in this  src="{{media url="wysiwyg/blogimg1.jpg"}}"

Comment: have you added above text in your blog content from backend ?

Comment: Yes the content is already their

Comment: you will get help from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961788/image-showing-like-img-alt-index-jpg-wysiwyg-src-media-url-i)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve we have to use the filter , and everything gonna fine

```
  Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($collection->short_content)
```